# Swiper React: как в компоненте Swiper, добавить правильно html разметку, чтобы она была в самом начале

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper

Есть слайдер swiper(react). Мне нужно чтобы **div** с классом **wrapperTitle** был перед компонентом **swiperSlide**, чтобы в **html** разметке сперва был **div** с классом **wrapperTitle**, а потом сам элемент с изображениями(**swiper-wrapper**),  где находиться коллекция изображений. На скриншоте **wrapperTitle** находится в конце, мне нужно чтобы он был перед **swiper-wrapper**. Я не сильно еще разобрался с react-swiper, по-этому прошу помощи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 <div className={styles.wrapperCard}>
      <Swiper
        slidesPerView={4}
        spaceBetween={30}
        simulateTouch={false}
        loop
        modules={[Navigation]}
        navigation={{
          clickable: true,
        }}
        className={styles.swiper}>
        <div className={styles.wrapperTitle}>
          <h2 className={styles.title}>Our you have to buy</h2>
          <h1 className={styles.title}>Product</h1>
        </div>
        {cards.map((card) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={card.id} className={styles.swiperSlide}>
            <Card
              id={card.id}
              img={card.img}
              title={card.title}
              price={card.price}
              isAdd={(object) => objectCard(object)}
            />
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </div>
```

Comment: а для чего вам блок `className={styles.wrapperTitle}` внутри компонента `Swiper`?

Comment: У react swiper, ширина,длина 100% от внутреннего контента. А так как у самого swiper стиль overfllov: hidden, я не могу за его предели swiper разместить текст или кнопки навигации. А если точнее позиционировать элементи внутри swiper, но за его пределы

Comment: ну кнопки навигации элементарно стилями ставятся на любое место. А на счет текста все равно не понял . Тест будет относится к каждому слайду ? или для всего слайдера? если для всего слайдера вынесите его перед самим свайпером

Comment: Вы меня не правильно поняли. Я это делаю из-за кнопок навигации. Они находятся внутри swiper как html, но стилями они должны быть за пределами swiper, а у swiper overflove: hidden. Я добавил изображение для более понятной полноты проблемы

Comment: убираете все из свайпера. Делаете просто 2 компанента `ButtonNext` `ButonPrev`. На них вешаете событие onClick и там переключаете слайды. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73984522/11334182

Comment: мда... не приятно что придется делать кнопки, но видимо выбора нет